# AngularJS How to avoid app.run() of being executed in every test?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have an angular application which executes some logic in `app.run`. It includes some `$http` calls to load a config.json file and restore user session if needed.

I am using Jasmine to write all my unit tests. Today, I have realised I am invoking the `run` function with every single test since at the top of every describe I am doing:

```
beforeEach(module('myapp'));
```

This is causing me a real headache since so far, the only workaround I find for this is mocking the services which are making the requests in all my `describes`. It sounds extremely not correct for me and even I don´t think I will have the chance to spy on these services executed in run phase.

However, the application works fine and as far as I understand the `app.run()` is a good place to make those calls.

Is there a way to sort this out?

Comment: The canonical way would be to modularize your application. Main app module shouldn't be instantiated unless you're testing its functionality. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: The doc also gives approach (example at the bottom) how to avoid instantiation of main module via inline `module` and `inject`

Comment: Thanks @KirillSlatin. I have read that really useful link and yeah, I am going to break my app down in different modules. I was already worrying about the number of services injected in my only one module. I will post the solution when I got the code.

Comment: Also, related with angular best practices I found this post which is even recommended by google: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KirillSlatin pointed out, the workaround for this is splitting your app in several modules.

This way, every module can execute its own config and run blocks. Only services for a module need to mock run block in case they need it.

```
angular.module("app", ["app.core"]).config(function() {}).run(function(){});
angular.module("app.core", []).config(function() {}).run(function(){});
```

Some very good practices can be found in the following post that many of you may already know: [github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide](http://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)